# Use .find() to change src on image jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a script where the image sources change when the mouse hovers over the div. I've figured out how to change the source by selecting the image by itself, but I instead want to change the source by selecting the images within the divs using .find(). Something's not working?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Declare Arrays
  imgList = new Array();
  imgList["ref1"] = new Array();
  imgList["ref2"] = new Array();
  imgList["ref3"] = new Array();

//Set values for each mouse state
  imgList["ref1"]["out"] = "http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg";
  imgList["ref1"]["over"] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/European_cat_02.jpg/400px-European_cat_02.jpg";
  imgList["ref2"]["out"] = "http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg";
  imgList["ref2"]["over"] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/European_cat_02.jpg/400px-European_cat_02.jpg";
  imgList["ref3"]["out"] = "http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg";
  imgList["ref3"]["over"] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/European_cat_02.jpg/400px-European_cat_02.jpg";


//Add the swapping functions
  $("div").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", imgList[ $(this).attr("id") ]["over"]);
  });
  $("div").mouseout(function(){
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", imgList[ $(this).attr("id") ]["out"]);
  });

});
```

```css
div  {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg" id="ref1"/>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg" id="ref1"/>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg" id="ref1"/>
</div>
```

Comment: `imgList` and all its `ref`-elements should be objects and not arrays

Comment: In my humble opinion, you have complicated it. Can I make an easier method for you?

Comment: Yes please! One thing to add- I want to select the div instead of the image itself because there will be a pseudo element before the img that will appear on mouseover as well

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare objects not array

```
// Declare objects

      imgList = {};
      imgList["ref1"] = {};
      imgList["ref2"] = {};
      imgList["ref3"] = {};
```

`$(this).attr("id")` meaning you are look for attr `id` from `div` not from `img`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Declare objects

  imgList = {};
  imgList["ref1"] = {};
  imgList["ref2"] = {};
  imgList["ref3"] = {};

//Set values for each mouse state
  imgList["ref1"]["out"] = "http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg";
  imgList["ref1"]["over"] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/European_cat_02.jpg/400px-European_cat_02.jpg";
  imgList["ref2"]["out"] = "http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg";
  imgList["ref2"]["over"] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/European_cat_02.jpg/400px-European_cat_02.jpg";
  imgList["ref3"]["out"] = "http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg";
  imgList["ref3"]["over"] = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/78/European_cat_02.jpg/400px-European_cat_02.jpg";


  
  //Add the swapping functions

  $("div").mouseover(function() {
   $(this).find('img').attr("src", function() {
      return imgList[this.id].over; 
   });

  });
  $("div").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", function() {
      return imgList[this.id].out; 
   });
  });

});
```

```css
div  {
  width:100px;
  display:inline-block;
}
img {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg" id="ref1"/>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg" id="ref1"/>
</div>
<div>
  <img src="http://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/600x600p/photos.demandstudios.com/142/14/fotolia_1230128_XS.jpg" id="ref1"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three problems with your script/markup.

1. ids have to be unique `<img id="ref1" />` but this is probably only a typo
2. `imgList` and the `ref`-elements should be objects `{}` and not arrays `[]` (JavaScript has no associative arrays)
3. the value of `this` in those two places:

```js
$(this).find('img').attr("src", imgList[ $(this).attr("id") ]["over"]);
$(this).find('img').attr("src", imgList[ $(this).attr("id") ]["out"]);
```

`this` is in this case the `<div>` element, hence `$(this).attr("id")` returns the `id` of the `<div>` element and not the `id` of the `<img>` element.

One way to fix this is to use [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

> **attributeName**
>   Type: `String`
>   The name of the attribute to set.
>
> **function**
>   Type: `Function( Integer index, String attr )` => `String` or `Number`
>   A function returning the value to set. `this` is the current
>   element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the
>   old attribute value as arguments

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Declare Arrays
  var imgList = {
    ref1: {
      out: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg/320px-065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg",
      over: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Katzen_und_ihre_Sonnenpl%C3%A4tze.jpg/320px-Katzen_und_ihre_Sonnenpl%C3%A4tze.jpg"
    },
    ref2: {
      out: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg/320px-065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg",
      over: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Katzen_und_ihre_Sonnenpl%C3%A4tze.jpg/320px-Katzen_und_ihre_Sonnenpl%C3%A4tze.jpg"
    },
    ref3: {
      out: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg/320px-065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg",
      over: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Katzen_und_ihre_Sonnenpl%C3%A4tze.jpg/320px-Katzen_und_ihre_Sonnenpl%C3%A4tze.jpg"
    }
  };

  //Add the swapping functions
  $("div").mouseover(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", function() {
      return imgList[this.id].out;
    });
  });
  $("div").mouseout(function() {
    $(this).find('img').attr("src", function() {
      return imgList[this.id].over;
    });
  });
});
```

```css
div { width: 200px; height: 100px }
img { width: 100%; height: 100% }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg/320px-065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg" id="ref1" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg/320px-065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg" id="ref2" />
</div>
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/43/065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg/320px-065-Barcelona-Cat-2.jpg" id="ref3" />
</div>
```